# unable to understand the last step in this code

Tags: c++

*function for constructing a tree from  inorder and preorder*

```
struct treenode * construct(struct listnode *inptr,struct listnode * preptr ,int num)
{    
    struct treenode *temp;
    struct listnode *q;
    int i,j;
    if(num==0)
    return NULL;
    temp=(struct treenode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    temp->info=preptr->info;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    if(num==1)/*if only one node  in tree*/
    return temp;
    q=inptr;
    for(i=q;q->info!=preptr->info;i++) q=q->next;
    /*now q points to root node in inorder list and the number of nodes in its left tree is i*/
    /*for left subtree*/
    temp->lchild=construct(inptr,preptr->next,i);
    /*for right subtree*/
    for(j=1;j<=i+1;j++) preptr=preptr->next;
    temp->rchild=construct(q->next,preptr,num-i-1);//unbale to understand this step as after node G construction value of i and num would be same this would result in -1
    return temp;
}/*end of construct */
```

**Question:** I can not understand what do we want to achieve by `temp->rchild=construct(q->next,preptr,num-i-1);`

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The syntax? The logic? Please be more specific.

Comment: It calls that function recursively.

Comment: @MarounMaroun  logic is not clear  as after hand debugging i found that value of i and num would be same at some step and there wont be a base case for termination i found this code in a data structure book

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ logic is not clear as after hand debugging i found that value of i and num would be same at some step and there wont be a base case for termination i found this code in a data structure book

Comment: @codewarrior `if(num==1)/*if only one node  in tree*/` is the condition to end the recursion.

Comment: `i` is initialized with `q`, which is a pointer to a struct. That shouldn't compile without an explicit cast, and `i` will be garbage after that. It should probably be `i=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder is `[Lin]N[Rin]` and Preorder is `N[Lpr][Rpr]`.

This function picks first node N from Preorder and construct left sub-child from Inorder list (with aid of preorder) and right subchild from Inorder list (with aid of preorder) after N.

This code achieves this by recursion with following terminating condition

```
if(num==1)/*if only one node  in tree*/
    return temp;
```

**About step you don't understand**
`for(j=1;j<=i+1;j++) preptr=preptr->next;` would advance preptr beyond N and [Lpr] and in next step it is used to construct the right sub-tree. It uses information from `for(i=q;q->info!=preptr->info;i++) q=q->next;` step before which counts the number of nodes in left sub-tree. So when you call the function revursively:

> q->next is pointing to [Rin]
>  preptr is pointing to [Rpr]
>   num-i-1 is the number of nodes in right subtree

**As a side note**
`for(i=q;q->info!=preptr->info;i++) q=q->next;` should be `for(i=0;q->info!=preptr->info;i++) q=q->next;`. Notice `q` is replaced with `0`

Comment: can you please give me the code to test the above function so that i can check it debugging